# How to check Mongo DB field value contains .(Dot)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to display all documents which field should contain (.)dot

I am using following Query to display field(name) contains (.)dot, But it's display everything in collection,

```
db.getCollection('test').find({
    "name": { $regex : ".*..*" }
})
```

Kindly let me know how to get document list which 'name' field contains (.)dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I got the MongoDB documents for field value that contains.(Dot) using the following Query.

//MongoDB Query - Get document list if name field value contains .(Dot),
db.getCollection('test').find(
{
    "name": { $regex : ".*\\.." }
})

Thanks & Regards,
Madhumathi Velusamy.
```